# Constructing an expression involving Kronecker delta and Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: kronecker-symbol

Let $i,j,k,l\in\{0,1,2\}$. I am looking for a simple expression $f(i,j,k,l)$ involving only (Kronecker delta)
$$\delta_{ab}=\cases{1&if $a=b$\\0&else},$$
and (Levi-Civita symbol)
$$\epsilon_{ab} = \cases{1&if $a<b$\\-1&if $a>b$\\0&if $a=b$},$$
and maybe constants, such that $f$ is non-zero if, and only if $\{i,j\}\neq\{k,l\}$. It would be perfect if the values taken by $f$ were only $\pm1$ or $0$, but it's not so necessary. Does anyone have one such expression under hand? Also, general techniques for constructing them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we nest the symbols, as in $\delta_{\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}}$? Also, note that it's always possible using only $\delta$ since you can construct the elementary checks such as $(i,j)=(2,1)$ and similar, and then multiplication is logical AND and addition is logical OR. It's just that the expression is not going to be simple. You can then construct all $\{\,(i,j,k,l)\,{:}\,\{i,j\}=\{k,l\}\,\}$ because this set is finite.

Comment: @yo' Yes, I know, I allowed $\epsilon$ because it might give a shorter expression than just using $\delta$. I would rather avoid nesting the symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$f(i,j,k,l)=\bigl(1-[ik][jl]\bigr)\bigl(1-[il][jk]\bigr),$$ where we denote $[ij]=\delta_{ij}$ for convenience.

Proof: Examine $[ik][jl]+[il][jk]$. It is one if either $(i,j)=(k,l)$ or $(i,j)=(l,k)$. It is two if both conditions are satisfied, which means all four numbers are equal. Whence $[ik][jl]+[il][jk]-[ik][jl][il][jk]$ is the negation of what you want.