# Short notation for specific multiplication

Tags: vectors

Say I have the product $A_iB_jC_kD_l$ which I know to be equal to $1$ iff $i=k$, $j=l$, and $i\ne j$.  It equals $-1$ iff $i=l$, $j=k$, and $i\ne j$.  And it equals $0$ otherwise.  How do I write this in a compact notation?  The $\pm 1$ or $0$ part reminds me of the Levi-Civita symbol, but I can't seem to think of a combination of Levi-Civita and Kronecker deltas that'll give me the right thing here.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829624/constructing-an-expression-involving-kronecker-delta-and-levi-civita-symbol/1829641#1829641

Comment: Doesn't $(1-\delta_{ij})(\delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} - \delta_{il} \delta_{jk})$ work? I don't see how it could be simplified. Also, what are the possible values for the indices?